# How to Persist CollectionType in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I'm getting Following Error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\Item#sizeQtyAttr' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\SizeQtyAttributes@0000000078a80e200000000074b3b674. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\SizeQtyAttributes#__toString()' to get a clue.

Class Item

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="items")
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=SizeQtyAttributes::class, mappedBy="item")
 */
private $sizeQtyAttr;
```

CLass SizeQtyAttributes

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Item::class, inversedBy="SizeQtyAttr")
 */
private $item;
```

Controller

```
    public function postProduct(Request $request, SluggerInterface $slugger, CategoryTreeAdminOptionList $categories): Response
{
    
    $item = new Item();   
    $form = $this->createForm(ItemType::class, $item);
    $categories->getCategoryList($categories->buildTree());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

        $item = $form->getData();
        $item_category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Category::class)->find($request->request->get('item_category'));
        //dd($item->getSizeQtyAttributes()->getAttrName());
        $file_image = $form->get('image')->getData();
        if($file_image){
          //image stuff
        }
        $item->setCategory($item_category);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($item);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('post_product');
    }
```

I tried with adding cascade={"persist"} but didn't work. Did I miss something? Please Help.

Comment: Can you post your entity including the `cascade`? It should be  `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=SizeQtyAttributes::class, mappedBy="item", cascade={"persist"})`

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that you don't need the line `$item = $form->getData();`. Since you've created your $item object a couple lines above and passed it to the form, Symfony handles the population with the form data for you.

Comment: @fun2life thanks man it worked. I spinned my head for few days on this..